# some service classes not showing up in sonar code coverage

Tags: class, code-coverage, sonarqube

I have close to 40 service classes in my project. When I am running SONAR on the project; and clicking on 'Code Coverage', and navigating down to the package, it's omitting some classes; although i haven't put these classes in SONAR's exclusion list.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Only classes with less than 100% coverage appear in the coverage drilldown. So if these classes are fully covered, it is expected behavior not to see them.